# validate radiobuttonlist in a gridview using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to validate that each radiobuttonlist has been selected.  the radiobuttonlist is dynamically created from a sql database.  The following line errors out "if (MyRadio[j].checked) {", the error is "checked' is null or not an object".  The following is the code. Thank you

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="Server">
    <cc1:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" CssClass="ajax__myTab" Width="100%" ScrollBars="Horizontal">
        <cc1:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" HeaderText="" Enabled="true">
            <HeaderTemplate>Main</HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: right">Audit Status:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAuditStatus" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem>InProgress</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Completed</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </cc1:TabPanel>
        <cc1:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server" HeaderText="" Enabled="true">
            <HeaderTemplate>Questions</HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridViewQuestions" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="1" DataKeyNames="Pkey" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical">
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnPkey" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("Pkey") %>' />
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnRequiresAnAnswer" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("RequiresAnAnswer") %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Answer">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Visible="false">
                                    <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>N/A</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <HeaderStyle Width="130px" />
                            <ItemStyle Width="130px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Silver" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </cc1:TabPanel>
    </cc1:TabContainer>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function fcnUpdateMain() {

        var MyStatus = document.getElementById("<%=ddlAuditStatus.ClientID%>").value
        var grid = document.getElementById("<%= GridViewQuestions.ClientID %>");

        if (grid.rows.length > 0) {

            for (i = 2; i < grid.rows.length + 1; i++) {

                if (i < 10) {
                    i = "0" + i
                } else {
                    i = i
                }

                var MyReqAnswer = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_GridViewQuestions_ctl" + i + "_hdnRequiresAnAnswer").value
                var MyRadio = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_GridViewQuestions_ctl" + i + "_RadioButtonList1")

                if (MyStatus == "Completed") {

                    if (MyReqAnswer == "Yes") {

                        var options = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
                        for( x = 0; x < options.length; ++x ) {
                            if(options[x].type == "radio") {

                                 for (var j = 0; j < MyRadio.length; j++) {
                                    if (MyRadio[j].checked) {
                                    } else {
                                        alert("You must select an answer for all questions.")
                                        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_TabContainer1_TabPanel2_GridViewQuestions_ctl" + i + "_ddlProductInterest").focus()
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've already realised that RadioButtonList controls are rendered as a `<table>` with each radio button as an `<input>` within that table.  Therefore getting a handle on RadioButtonList1 and trying to access it as an array using `MyRadio[j]` isn't going to work.

I think the following line:

```
var options = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
```

Should instead read:

```
var options = MyRadio.getElementsByTagName("input")
```

That will give you just a collection of the input tags within that RadioButtonList control rather than all those on the page.  Once you have that options collection, you shouldn't need to refer to the RadioButtonList control again.

I understand that this is drastically simplified over what you have, but here's an example for you:

```
<form runat="server">
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" id="RadioButtonList1">
    <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>N/A</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<input type="button" onclick="fcnUpdateMain()" value="Click" />
<script type="text/javascript">

    function fcnUpdateMain()
    {
        var MyRadio = document.getElementById("<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID%>")
        var options = MyRadio.getElementsByTagName("input")
        var somethingChecked = false;
        for( x = 0; x < options.length; ++x )
        {
            if (options[x].checked)
            {
                somethingChecked = true;
            }
        }
        if (!somethingChecked)
        {
            alert("You must select an answer for all questions.")
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
</form>
```

Comment: But how did you get this to work @Mike, if the RadioButtonList is inside a Gridview? Shouldn't you find the parent node first and then FindControl the RadioButtonList control? Because the above did not work for me. I still get "radiobuttonlist1 not in current context" error. Thanks

Comment: I did this all on the client side. The fcnUpdateMain() is javascript function.  I call the function on the submit button.  Does that make sense?